# Python enumerate() tqdm progress-bar when reading a file?

Tags: python, progress-bar, enumerate, tqdm

I can't see the tqdm progress bar when I use this code to iterate my opened file:

```
with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(tqdm(f)):
        print("line #: %s" % i)
        for j in tqdm(range(line_size)):
            ...
```

What's the right way to use tqdm here?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Avoid printing inside the loop when using `tqdm`. Also, use `tqdm` only on the first for-loop, and not on the inner for-loop.

```
with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(tqdm(f)):
        for j in range(line_size):
            ...
```

Some notes on using `enumerate` and its usage in `tqdm` are available [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tqdm#faq-and-known-issues).

Answer (score 35):

`tqdm` is not displaying a progress bar because it does not know the number of lines in the file.

In order to display a progress bar, you will first need to scan the file and count the number of lines, then pass it to `tqdm` as the `total`.

```
from tqdm import tqdm

with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    num_lines = sum(1 for line in f)

with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in tqdm(f, total=num_lines):
        print(line)
```

Reminder: A `for` loop over the file object `f` will iterate over lines, reading until the next newline character is encountered.

Answer (score 13):

I'm trying to do the same thing on a file containing all Wikipedia articles. So I don't want to count the total lines before starting processing. Also it's a bz2 compressed file, so the len of the decompressed line overestimates the number of bytes read in that iteration, so...

```
with tqdm(total=Path(filepath).stat().st_size) as pbar:
    with bz2.open(filepath) as fin:
        for i, line in enumerate(fin):
            if not i % 1000:
                pbar.update(fin.tell() - pbar.n)
            # do something with the decompressed line
    # Debug-by-print to see the attributes of `pbar`: 
    # print(vars(pbar))
```

Thank you [Yohan Kuanke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6826354/yohan-karunanayake) for your deleted answer. If moderators undelete it you can crib mine.

Comment: This gives the right output but I found that calling `fin.tell()` / `pbar.update()` for every line of the file dramatically slowed down the iteration speed.  Using an `if i % 100 == 0:` condition to update the pbar less frequently gave me a 10x speedup.

Comment: Excellent idea @BenPage! I'll add your optimization to the answer

Comment: You can't use this technique if you use the `csv` module to read your file (for example, with `csv_lines=csv.reader(fin)`). You get the error `OSError: telling position disabled by next() call` when you call `fin.tell()`

Comment: @Eponymous Yea. The code is designed to work on file pointers, not any arbitrary iterable. You have to apply the `enumerate()` wrapper and the code in this for loop around the *file stream object* rather than any other object (such as a `csv_reader`)... even if it's derived from a file stream. It may not pass through all the methods of a file stream object (such as .tell). You would need to create a generator using this code and put that generator inside the `csv_reader` parens e.g. `csv_reader((... for i, line in enumerate(fin))) `.

Answer (score 6):

If you are reading from a very large file, try this approach:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import os

file_size = os.path.getsize(filename)
lines_read= []
pbar = tqdm.tqdm(total=file_zize, unit="MB")
with open(filename, 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as file:
    while (line := file.readline()):
        lines_read.append(line)
        pbar.update(s.getsizeof(line)-sys.getsizeof('\n'))
pbar.close()
```

I left out the processing you might want to do before the `append(line)`

**EDIT:**

I changed `len(line)` to `s.getsizeof(line)-sys.getsizeof('\n')` as `len(line)` is not an accurate representation of how many bytes were actually read (see other posts about this). But even this is not 100% accurate as sys.getsizeof(line) is not the real length of bytes read but it's a "close enough" hack if the file is very large.

I did try using f.tell() instead and subtracting a file pos delta in the while loop but f.tell with non-binary files is very slow in Python 3.8.10.

As per the link below, I also tried using f.tell() with Python 3.10 but that is still very slow.

If anyone has a better strategy, please feel free to edit this answer but please provide some performance numbers before you do the edit. Remember that counting the # of lines prior to doing the loop is not acceptable for very large files and defeats the purpose of showing a progress bar altogether (try a 30Gb file with 300 million lines for example)

**Why f.tell() is slow in Python when reading a file in non-binary mode**
https://bugs.python.org/issue11114

Comment: Thanks a lot , I"m confuzzing about how to use tqdm  for  out of Memory Big file

Comment: If you import tqdm from tqdm, then remove one of the tqdm from the initial pbar statement-- i.e., pbar = tqdm(total=file_zize, unit="MB").

Answer (score 2):

In the case of reading a file with `readlines()`, following can be used:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
with open(filename) as f:
    sentences = tqdm(f.readlines(),unit='MB')
```

the `unit='MB'` can be changed  to 'B' or 'KB' or 'GB' accordingly.