# Is there a way to use tqdm function while reading the file in order to show the progress of the reading process in Python?

Tags: python, progress-bar, file-read, tqdm

If there is another way to show the progress through some other function?

```
with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    contents = f.read()
```

Comment: What goes wrong when you try to use `tqdm`? per [Python enumerate() tqdm progress-bar when reading a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48437189/python-enumerate-tqdm-bar-when-reading-a-file). Also, here is link to [tqdm doc](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm).

Answer (score 2):

It may help you.

```
import os
from tqdm import tqdm

with tqdm(total=os.path.getsize(file)) as pbar:
   with open(file, "rb") as f:
      for l in f:
          pbar.update(len(l))
          ...
```

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/51693787